# Recursively stage all git-submodule reference updates

Tags: git, jenkins, git-submodules

I'm working on getting Jenkins to play nice with git submodules. The current process is to pull the parent repo and the submodule, do the builds, bump the version, stage a bunch of changes, tag the repos, commit and push.

I'm adding an option to update the submodule reference, and that seems to also be working fine (after adding tracking branch info to the .gitmodules file). However, I am not having much luck in automatically (or, maybe recursively) staging all tracking branch reference updates into a commit.

So, in order to stage the reference change, I would need to do a `git add /path/to/sub`. This might become a problem if/when additional submodules are tracked, esepcially when I'm trying to have the stage/commit/tag operation as a Jenkins global library function.

To be clear, I am not trying to commit the **changes made inside the submodule**, but rather the **change to parent repo's reference to the submodule sha**.

I'm not sure if such a command already exsits, but I haven't been able to find it. I am envisioning something along the lines of `git add --submodule-paths`. I feel like it can be done by iterating over the submodules with `git submodule foreach` and then doing something, but after a few hours I haven't come up with anything.

Is there a good way to do this?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. Here is what I ended up doing, in case anybody else is interested:

```
git submodule foreach "git tag <some_version>"
git submodule foreach "cd $toplevel; git commit $path -m '<some_version> - Updating submodule reference'"
git submodule foreach "git push --tags"
```

`$toplevel` is predefined inside the `foreach` for git, and is the absolute path to the root of the parent workspace.

`$path` is predefined inside the `foreach` for git, and is the relative path from the parent repo to the root of the submodule.